# Sweave: run a bat file in Windows 7

Tags: miktex, windows, sweave

When I run a RNW file inside RStudio compilation is working. But when I try to run the same RNW file through a BAT file, compilation is not working. I am a Win 7 user, using MixTex...

Actually my aim is to work on a LaTeX editor like TeXMaker and compile a RNW files through a BAT file. After compilation I would like to get a PDF file...

On Rstudio I create a file named "main.Rnw" then I simply press on "Compile PDF" then I get a nice PDF output.

But on texmaker I created the same "main.Rnw" but when I create my a "run.bat" file on the same directory, nothing is working. My "run.bat" contains:

> Sweave main.Rnw

I don't find a solution to my issue...

---

My "main.Rnw" code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for lorem ipsum text
\begin{document}
\title{Test sweave}
\maketitle

%fake text
\lipsum[1]

%just a boxplot text
<<fig=TRUE>>=
test <- c(-10,8,6,4,2,0,2,4,6,8,10)
boxplot(test)
@

%fake text
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of `Sweave main.Rnw` in your `run.bat` file, use `R.exe CMD Sweave --pdf main.Rnw` and run it. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda thank you this solved my issue. But before I had to change create a PATH "C:\Program Files\R\R-2.15.2\bin\x64"  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think there is such a thing as `Sweave.exe` in R under Windows. There is only `R CMD Sweave`.

The other way is to define a custom command as illustrated here: http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/editors/ (it is using `knitr` instead of Sweave, but the basic idea is the same)

Comment: Hello, interesting. By the way do you recommend me to use knitr instead of sweave ?

Comment: Hello, actually I've just seen that knitr is like an impovement of Sweave, I'm interested to use it. It's working very well with classic latex (pdflatex). However, what's the .bat to get it with xelatex?

Comment: @Swiss12000 you can call `knit2pdf(..., compiler = 'xelatex')` if you want to use XeLaTeX

Comment: Ok actually I got it "C:/Program Files/R/R-2.15.2/bin/Rscript.exe" -e "knitr::knit2pdf('%.Rnw',  compiler = 'xelatex')"  However, now I still don't get how to use knitr when i have some input it's working on the main file but not on the child rnw ...

Comment: are you using `<<child='foo.Rnw'>>=`? Sweave uses `\SweaveInput{}` but `knitr` does not support it any more: http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/sweave/

Comment: yeah ok is good working, I'll also read the documentation and see your website. Thanks a lot for your package ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that Sewave is in your Path? Try running `Sweave main.Rnw` at the Windows command line. If it doesn't work, you will have to use the complete path to the file, e.g. `C:\Program Files\...\sweave.exe` to get it to work.

If that doesn't work, try calling the batch file like this:

```
cmd /C " "batch_file" "arg1" "arg2" ... "
```

This may, for some reason, be required if UAC is off.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).